# Programmatically remove css imported from Angular component styles:[] array in window top frame

Tags: angular, webpack

I have an angular component with the following definition:

method 1 (works but polluted global scope even after component destroyed)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-somecomponent',
  templateUrl: './somecomponent.component.html',
  styles: ['@import "https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"'],
  styleUrls: ['./somecomponent.component.scss']
})
```

I want bootstrap css to apply only to this component, because I invoke a 3rd party library that relies on it to render a form.  As soon as I load the component, the bootstrap cdn css package gets loaded in a global scope.  Destroying the component does not get rid of it.

[image: bootstrap loaded once component loads]

How can I use javascript to remove it?  I want to remove it on ngOnDestroy so it doesn't pollute the global scope.

I've already tried moving bootstrap.css to the local folder and importing it into the styles array like this:

method 2 (doesn't work, when form is rendered it has no styling)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-somecomponent',
  templateUrl: './somecomponent.component.html',
  styles: ['./bootstrap.css'],
  styleUrls: ['./somecomponent.component.scss']
})
```

This compiles fine but when I render the form with the 3rd party tool it doesn't seem to actually have access to bootstrap.css

I call the form rendering code in noOnInit.  I'm using formio for this:

```
ngOnInit() {
   Formio.createForm(frmSrc, ...).then((form)=>{...});
}
```

I want bootstrap to exist while this component is rendered then removed when this component is destroyed.

Comment: Hi, Do you try to import the ```./bootstrap.css``` in your ```somecomponent.component.scss```